# is it possible to treat symbolic links as actual directories when including them in PHP

Tags: php

I have a folder that looks like this sorta

```
/optik
   |- shadow
    - auth.ini
   |- htdocs
       |- index.php
```

and I have an actual directory

```
/
  |- skel
      |- include.php
```

now, i made a symbolic link shadow from skel, so what ever I put in skel will appear in the shadow folder. I did this because I have dynamic files in skel that I would be changing from time to time, so i didn't want to keep having duplicate copies of the contents of skel in each of my users folders. So I thought of making a shortcut link to it.

But now I was looking to see if in my index.php i could do something like this

index.php

```
<?
   include "/optik/shadow/include.php";

   // content
```

and in my include.php

```
<?
   include "../auth.ini";

   // some stuff with auth.ini
```

My goal is that I want to know if I can use the symbolic link like an actual dir in PHP's eyes. Since from the symbolic links perspective it would need to go up 1 directory to access auth.ini, but in the actual skel directory that file doesn't exist and I would need to specify the entire directory path to my auth.ini. But since the user folders will all differ its impossible to know what directory path to specify.

How can I get something like this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP should respect symlinks and follow them as if they were standard directories.

However, you are still working from the original directory in which `index.php` resides. This means that the `include "../auth.ini";` call will be looking in `/optik` (the directory above `htdocs`) rather than the directory above that in which the included file resides.

You can use a combination of [realpath()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) and [dirname()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) to calculate the actual canonical paths of the files you want to get at.

Comment: right, the skeleton folder is outside of the user folder. in the user folder i can include the symbolic link folder path to the include.php but then how can i get the include.php to follow `include "../";` as if it was an actual file in the users folder.

Comment: Sorry, is `auth.ini` in the user's folder or not?

Comment: ...and it isn't currently working? because it should... what error do you get when you try the `include` call from `include.php`?

Comment: never mind, i got what you were saying and applied it to my script. You gave me the right idea thanks

Comment: @DaveRandom: PHP is not handling symlinks properly in some case like __FILE__ and __DIR__: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46260 I know that the last statement is "design decision", but this is wrong of course, it's a bug which no other runtime suffers from.

Answer (score 1):

Given your example, to include `optik/auth.ini` from your `optik/shadow/include.php` file that is itself included from `index.php`, you could use the following

```
// optik/htdocs/index.php

// First, add the `optik` directory to the include path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))),
    get_include_path()
));
include 'shadow/include.php';

// optik/shadow/include.php
include 'auth.ini';
```

As `index.php` is the parent file, setting the include path from there cascades into any other included files.

Now, in regards to symbolic links, what you're proposing should work fine. What you do have to keep in mind (and this is a massive PITA) is that the `__FILE__` and `__DIR__` constants will resolve symbolic links. PHP offers absolutely no way to determine the unresolved path of a symbolically linked file or directory.

To illustrate, even if you include your `include.php` file via the `shadow` symlink, using `__FILE__` in that file will **always** return `/skel/include.php`

See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38790

Comment: the only issue I have is that I don't know the username, since i will be including this blind. I have subdomains being made with usernames as the folders. And I wan't to create a skeleton to each new subdomain. But I also want to authenticate the user using my auth.ini that resides in the users folder which is what i'm trying to access from include.php

Comment: @s2xi Ah, I missed where your `index.php` file is under `optik/htdocs`. I've updated my answer