# php not resolving symbolic link

Tags: php

php does not seem to be resolving a symbolic link.

I am trying to add the target of a symbolic link to my include path in a php file, but php does not seem to recognize that the symbolic link leads to a directory, and therefore is not able to find the files I want to include.

For context, here are relevant directory details

```
$> pwd
/var/www/siteroot

$> ls -l 
content 
...
includes -> content/subdir/includes
...
public_html

$> ls includes/common/
default-home.php
```

And here is the php file from which I am trying to load the `default-home.php` page.

```
$> cat public_html/index.php
<?php
wanted_path="../includes/common" 
set_include_path($wanted_path.PATH_SEPARATOR.get_includes_path());
var_dump(is_dir($wanted_path)); # testing to see if the included path is a directory
var_dump(is_dir("../includes")); # test to see if the symbolic link alone resolves to a directory
include "default-home.php"; 
?>
```

Based on the above, when I go to the `index.php` webpage I would expect to see:

```
bool(true) bool(true)
...(output/contents of default-home.php)
```

However, the `is_dir()` calls result in False and False, and the error log shows

```
PHP Warning: include(default-home.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Based on what I have read about php, such as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326903/is-it-possible-to-treat-symbolic-links-as-actual-directories-when-including-them) and the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php), it seems that php usually resolves symbolic links by default, but perhaps my configuration is different?

Anyway, how can I make php locate files which are within a directory beneath a symbolic link?

I am using PHP 5.5.22 on the OpenBSD5.7 native httpd server. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

This turned out to be a permissions issue. To show the permissions and ownership:

```
$> ls -la
drwx-------   hilcharge daemon    ...  content
...
lrwxr------   hilcharge daemon    ... includes -> content/subdir/includes/
...
```

Even after changing permissions of `includes` target with `chmod -R -L 0755 includes`, the folders were still not being found.

To fix problem, I changed permissions of `content` and `subdir`.

Comment: Does the user running the web server have access to those directories?

Comment: Woops no they didn't, thanks. But I just did `chmod -R -L 0755 includes` and the problem still exists no noticeable change in output. The owner and group are the same too.

Comment: I added the output to the question, and found the solution. I had to change the permissions of all directories between the link and the target. I'm surprised that php says it cannot find the file, rather than saying permission denied. I remember having similar issue with perl cgi file a while ago too. Is there some documented reason for that?

Comment: Try including an absolute directory: /dir/dir/includes/common. Or just do echo get_include_path() to make sure it's built properly.

Comment: Ok i tried the absolute path and it worked too. But what do you mean included properly?

Comment: Try using `__DIR__` for a treat. :-p

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix point taken, I see that the normal path is resolved and then attempted to be loaded. I still don't understand why php would't generate a permissions error instead of a file not found error though.

Comment: @hilcharge - yea we got a SSD drive to move some heavy report writing to and gave some hiccups, dealing with the sym-link.  I think I just hardcode the path in out of frustration.

Answer (score 5):

I my case it was problem of open_basedir restrictions in php-fpm vhost config - set it like this:

```
php_admin_value[open_basedir]=/website/dir:/symbolic-link-original/dir
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP is throwing the file not found error because the user running the web server does not have proper access privileges to the files being included. PHP does not seem to throw a permissions error in this case.

Note that the user of the web-server must have access to the desired files via the **absolute** path of the targeted file, because symbolic links will be resolved to their normal path prior to being loaded.

This same behavior is used in `is_dir($path)`, as described in the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php).

**Short, insecure solution**

To allow the desired files to be included, execute `chmod` to give read permission to the user who is running the webserver (usually `www-data` for apache or `www` for the default OpenBSD httpd referenced in the question)

For example,

```
$> chmod -R -L 0755 content
# content is the root of the target of the symbolic link
```

will allow php to access the files, regardless of who the owner is

*NOTE*  `$> chmod -R -L 0755 **includes**` will NOT necessarily fix the issue, because the user may still not have access to the the desired file via its absolute path.

In any event, the above is certainly not minimum required privilege. For a better, more secure answer, see below.

**Longer, more secure answer**

Reference: [Serverfault canonical answer to website file permissions with apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver)

The web-server user should have the following permissions:

- read permission for the files being included
- read and execute permission for the the folders in which the include files exist (the **absolute** path)

The following solution is just one example of how to set permissions for the file, but may differ depending on required developer access etc.

To find the user running the server, execute the following:

```
$> ps -Aux | grep httpd
```

(hereinafter assumed to be `www`, being in a group of `www`)
Now change the group of the file

```
$> chown -R :www content/
```

Add read and execute permissions for the folders:

```
$> chmod -R 0750 content/
```

And finally give the server's group only read permission to the files being included

```
$> chmod 0740 content/subdir/includes/common/default-home.php
```

Now, the web-server has the permissions it needs to access the file.

Comment: Nice tip about the absolute path. I had to move my files from /root to a more appropriate place so that it could read them.