# Accessing files that are on another hard disk

Tags: php, image-processing

Recently I mounted another hard drive to `/mnt/sdb` on Debian server as the first hard disk was already full. Then, I started to upload files to the second hard drive such as images.

In order to access new files, I created a shortcut from `web` folder and linked to the new hard drive folder. I can access files through html and everything is working fine, but The problem is when I access files via php with functions such as `imagecreatefromjpeg` I receive following errors:

> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
> File(foldername/filename.jpg) is not within the allowed path(s):
>
> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(foldername/filename.jpg): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted

How can I access files with php functions?

Comment: Do you mean that I should use `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php not resolving symbolic link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633162/php-not-resolving-symbolic-link)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing your PHP is implemented as a module of **apache**, locate your **php.ini** file (it could be **/etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini**), you will find a not uncommented line beginning with `open_basedir =` and append the path to the directory where the pictures are, something like `/mnt/sdb/some_sub_directory`, using `:` as separator from the previous path.

After saving changes in the **php.ini** file, restart apache for applying these with some command like:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```