# PHP not able to resolve a path from symbolic link

Tags: php, symlink

I have purchased a Shared Hosting plan from [hostinger.com](https://hostinger.com). The control provided by them is **hPanel**. Recently, PHP 8.0 has been released and implemented on their server. Unfortunately, since the upgrade, the character limit in `include_path` variable has been limited to 150 characters. Now, my `include_path` string is over 400 characters, thanks to the fact that `include_path` cannot cannot read files from sub directories. I've raised ticket but their tech team has not bee  able to figure out why this happened, and are unable to rectify that.

They suggested me to try "symbolic links" to reduce length of `include_path`.

I have created a new symbolic link in **Putty** `/cdn/mycdn` targeting `/domains/kbcsurveyors.com/public_html/mycdn`, which is working in File Manager in hPanel.

[image: Screenshot of folder structure]

I have made a corresponding entry in `include_path` as `/home/<myusername>/cdn/mycdn`, and I had to mandatorily remove old string as hPanel was not allowing me to save the original because of 150 character limit.

Now in every script I where in had included files from directories in `include_path`, I am receiving error like -

> **Warning:** require_once(debug.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> **/home/my_user_name/domains/my_domain_name/public_html/test.php** on line **xxx**
>
> **Fatal error:** require_once(): Failed opening required 'debug.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear:/home/my_user_name/cdn:/')
> in **/home/my_user_name/domains/my_domain_name/public_html/test.php**
> on line **xxx**

On Googling, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633162/php-not-resolving-symbolic-link) post on StackOverflow. The post still has no accepted answer. According to this, the issue is with permissions. I have given full permissions on directory **mycdn** and its sub-directories.

[image: Permissions on shared folders]

Is there anything that I am doing wrong or is the server issue? The Hostinger tech support has given up.

Comment: I'd say you want to either include `mycdn/debug.php`, or you want to change that include path portion to `/home/my_user_name/cdn/mycdn` ...

Comment: But easier probably is to tell them that you will be happy to change to another hoster and that you are happy to give them your bank account to transfer back your money, since they cannot deliver what they should...

Comment: PHP does not recurse into directories under `include_path`, @arkascha's first comment is correct. However I disagree with the second as expecting _any_ host's tech support to debug your code for you is a bit much.

Comment: _“as hPanel was not allowing me to save the original because of 150 character limit”_ - if _that_ is the only place where something actually gets limited here, then you should probably be able to set your longer include path from _within_ your scripts, using `set_include_path` or `ini_set` – would that be an alternative, if you added this to a central config file or something, that gets included at the very beginning?

Comment: @Sammitch I agree that it is not the task of a technical support to debug application code. But that is not what I referred to. The support _does_ have the task to provide a usable platform, that includes an include path that is not clipped. The OP reported that the support did not succeed to fix that. That is what I as a customer would not accept.

Comment: @arkascha, Sammitch, Problem is definitely not with code. So, I am not expecting them to debug my code. They even don't know about their server config. Hilariously, it was I who figured out where the problem was. The tech team could not identify the problem. They had no idea of the new 150 character limit and they don't know how to fix that.

Comment: @CBore, Your solution is viable if I have to include the required scripts only in few scripts, probably in one domain / sub domain. I have over 300 scripts which require files like `debug.php` spread across 3 sub-domains. Changing all of them is, you know, pain-in-the-***.